# swift tableView.contentSize.height different iOS 13 and iOS 11 , why?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, ios13

my code is

```
paymentTableviewHeight.constant = paymentTableView.contentSize.height
```

but different result iOS versions. It works correctly when I try it on ios 11 but iOS 13 is shorter.

Comment: i am not changing anything. just i not understand why result is different length? tableview height shorter than on iOS 11

Comment: content size does not depend on the length of the cells? then, how can I set specific height? (I'm sorry I don't know enough)

Comment: No, content size is just a setting that tells the scroll view how much it can scroll. (A table view is a scroll view.) OK, so what's really going on here is you want a table view whose height exactly displays all of its cells at once? In that case the problem is that what you are doing is not how to do that.

Comment: yes I want it. how can I do this

Comment: Well, first off, _when_ does that code run? Is it in your `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: No, in    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {. ... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this problem by using below code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.tblViewHtConst.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height
}
```

Calling tableView.layoutIfNeeded() UITableView will calculate contentSize again and then you can set it to height constraint.

If layoutIfNeeded() is not called before setting height constraint, it is picking up value which is set in estimatedRowHeight, in my case it was large then actual content size and blank space was visible.